# How to find percentage using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, percentage

I want to find out the percentage of the people whose age are greater than 5 on the year of 2012 in summer semester at distinct venues. I wrote the SQL but it gave an error.

```
SELECT Venue,
100*COUNT
    (SELECT DISTINCT hid,
    q1 FROM raw_data 
    WHERE q2 > 5 
    AND Year=2012 
    AND Semester='summer' 
    GROUP BY Venue)
    /(SELECT DISTINCT hid,q1 
     FROM raw_data 
     WHERE Year=2012 
     AND Semester='summer' 
     GROUP BY Venue) 
AS "%" 
FROM raw_data 
WHERE Year=2012 
AND Semester='summer' 
GROUP BY Venue
```

Comment: The argument to `COUNT()` has to be either `*` or an expression that returns a single column, it can't be a `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.Venue, 100*IFNULL(t1.ct, 0)/t2.ct AS '%'
FROM (
    SELECT Venue, COUNT(DISTINCT hid, q1) AS ct
    FROM raw_data 
    WHERE q2 > 5
    AND Year = 2012
    AND Semester = 'summer'
    GROUP BY Venue) AS t1
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT Venue, COUNT(DISTINCT hid, q1) AS ct
    FROM raw_data
    WHERE Year = 2012
    AND Semester = 'summer'
    GROUP BY Venue) AS t2
ON t1.Venue = t2.Venue
```

I use a `RIGHT JOIN` so we'll get `0%` for Venues that have no people older than 5.

Comment: It shows the warning

#1052 - Column 'Venue' in field list is ambiguous

But my table fields are 

id  rid  user_id  hid  q1  q2  q3  q4  q5  q6  q7  q8  q9  q10  q11  q12  q13  q14  Venue  Semester  Year  completed_status  is_completed  is_delete  status

Comment: I needed to specify `t2.Venue` in the outer `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Could you please explain it widely actually I'm a newbie in SQL section so I am not getting your term.... sorry for this irritation...

Comment: Each subquery returns a column named `Venue`. So you need to specify which subquery's `Venue` column should be selected. Otherwise it's ambiguous.

Comment: And I used `t2` because `t1` might not return anything if there are no people older than 5 at that venue.

Comment: if you still don't understand, I think you need to hit the books. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for learning what you're doing, and I'm not going to try to tutor you on the basics of SQL.